# Why can I not run a cordova app on a real ios device, after the installation of the cordova-mfp-push plugin?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

**Environment:** 
MAC EL Capitan 10.11.6 , xCode Version 7.3.1, Node version: v5.5.0, Cordova version: 6.3.1, cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2016070407, MobileFirst Platform Foundation Command Line Interface (CLI): 8.0.0-2016070716

**Question:**
Why can I not run a cordova app on a real ios device, after the installation of the cordova-mfp-push plugin?
The ios app runs in the ios simulator.
Who had the same problem and how did you find it?

**Backround:**
I have a cordova app which was working with mfp8 push.

Because of the Apple Certification expiration problem (https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/), I had to recreate the certificates.

**Problem:**
After the recreation of the certifications I tried to run the app on my device.
But I got the certification error. Based on this I tried to run other Cordova Apps on my iOS device and this was possible.

Based on this finding I decide to add and remove the cordova plugins and check, when will this problem appear.

**Finding:**
My finding is: when I add the cordova-mfp-push plugin, then the problem with the certification appears in xcode.

I guess the reason is the cordova-mfp-push plugin automatically switch on the functionality  **“Backround Modes -> remote notifications”**.

Here you can see the two situations with the ios app:

1. Before add cordova-mfp-push to the cordova app:

In xCode running app ... ok the MFP push lib can not be found, but this is clear why.

[image]

In xCode no additional options enabled

[image]

2. After add cordova-mfp-push to the cordova app:

Console output

```
IBMs-MBP:MobileClientV3 tsuedbroecker$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp-push --save
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-mfp-push" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-mfp-push" for android
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-mfp" already installed on android.
Installing "cordova-plugin-mfp-push" for ios
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-mfp" already installed on ios.
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-mfp-push" to config.xml
IBMs-MBP:MobileClientV3 tsuedbroecker$ cordova prepare
Running command: /Users/tsuedbroecker/Documents/tsuedbro/MobileBluemix/dev/mfp8beta/CheckApp/MobileClientV3/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/tsuedbroecker/Documents/tsuedbro/MobileBluemix/dev/mfp8beta/CheckApp/MobileClientV3
add to body class: platform-android
add to body class: platform-ios
will push strings array {"name":"lang","titles":["English (US)","English (UK)"],"values":["en-us","en-gb"]}
android preferences file was successfully generated
ios settings bundle was successfully generated
IBMs-MBP:MobileClientV3 tsuedbroecker$ cordova plugin list
cordova-plugin-app-preferences 0.99.2 "AppPreferences"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.2.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.2.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.3 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2016080320 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2016070407 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation - Push Notifications"
cordova-plugin-okhttp 2.0.0 "OkHttp"
cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog 1.3.1 "SpinnerDialog"
```

Problem to run on device:

[image]

Changed configuration in xCode by the plugin:

[image]

Comment: And if you then tick this option off?

Comment: When I tick this option off, it is still the same problem.

Comment: The issue noted when trying to run on device "Unable to install" does not look to be a cordova mfp push plugin issue. 
Can you please try running the native iOS push sample on the same device - signed with the same profile and do you see that working? Or does the same error message appear? If so, it could be a problem with certificates not being updated

Comment: So, I did download the https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PushNotificationsSwift/tree/release80 sample.
Setup the certifications. Configure existing MFP8 Server on BX. 
And the sample runs on my device and I can send push from the MFP server to my device. ... no problem with the swift sample

Comment: I copy my mobile project and renamed the cordova app new bundle ID, create new certifications, add to mfp server ... still the same problem. The problem only comes up, when the cordova-plugin-mfp-push is added.

Comment: hmm, I also did the sample with cordova https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PushNotificationsSwift/tree/release80 . 
This sample works. I did the same steps as in my cordova app. The difference is, in my app there are much more plugins then in is this small sample and the starting point of my app was ionic. ... and it worked before .. stange ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something was **broken** in my **old cordova project**.

**Thanks** to @Idan Adar and @Vivin K for their feedback.

I did following steps to get the cordova app running on ios device with push again.

1. I did the sample with cordova on github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/… . This sample works.
2. I added all my needed plugins to the copy of the working cordova push project:

   IBMs-MBP:MobileClientV4 tsuedbroecker$ ./add-cordova-plugins.sh
   --> Starting add cordova plugins
       ****** app-preferences *********
   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-app-preferences" via npm
   Installing "cordova-plugin-app-preferences" for ios
   app-settings.json not found: creating a sample file
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-app-preferences" to config.xml
       ****** camera *********
   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-camera" via npm
   Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for ios
   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" via npm
   Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for ios
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-camera" to config.xml
       ****** compat *********
   Plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on ios. Making it top-level.
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-compat" to config.xml
       ****** console *********
   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-console" via npm
   Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for ios
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-console" to config.xml
       ****** device *********
   Plugin "cordova-plugin-device" already installed on ios. Making it top-level.
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-device" to config.xml
       ****** dialogs *********
   Plugin "cordova-plugin-dialogs" already installed on ios. Making it top-level.
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-dialogs" to config.xml
       ****** geolocation *********
   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-geolocation" via npm
   Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" for ios
   Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on ios.
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-geolocation" to config.xml
       ****** globalization *********
   Plugin "cordova-plugin-globalization" already installed on ios. Making it top-level.
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-globalization" to config.xml
       ****** inappbrowser *********
   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" via npm
   Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" for ios
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" to config.xml
       ****** spinner-dialog*********
   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog" via npm
   Installing "cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog" for ios
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog" to config.xml
       ****** okhttp *********
   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-okhttp" via npm
   Installing "cordova-plugin-okhttp" for ios
   Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-okhttp" to config.xml
       ****** list cordova plugins *********
   cordova-plugin-app-preferences 0.99.2 "AppPreferences"
   cordova-plugin-camera 2.2.0 "Camera"
   cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
   cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
   cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
   cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
   cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.2.0 "Geolocation"
   cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.3 "Globalization"
   cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
   cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2016080320 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
   cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2016070407 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation - Push Notifications"
   cordova-plugin-okhttp 2.0.0 "OkHttp"
   cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog 1.3.1 "SpinnerDialog"
   cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
   cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
       ****** cordova prepare *********
   ios settings bundle was successfully generated
   --> Add cordova plugins DONE!
3. I copied the **www** and **resource** folder from my old project into the working cordova project.
4. I copied the **Ionic project file** also to from my old project into the working cordova project.
5. That is the result:

********* Steps ***********

1. Step -> start app from xCode

[image]

2. Step -> go to configure push

[image]

3. Step -> check push support

[image]

4. Step -> register device

[image]

5. Step -> send push from mfp server to registered mobile devices

[image]